# Erro no na conversão de list no Python

Tags: python

Estou com o seguinte problema:

```
lista1 = [3,4,5]
list(map(lambda x: x**3, lista1))
```

Deu esse erro:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-5e26f3f7b396> in <module>()
      2 lista1 = [3,4,5]
      3 lista2 = (map(lambda x: x**3, lista1))
----> 4 print(list(lista2))

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o por quê desse erro?

Comment: Poderia colocar o código completo, por favor?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss esse é o codigo completo eu rodo ele no jupyter notebook!

Comment: O código, [tal como postou](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DarkredAccurateResearch), não possui erros, então você deve ter executado outras coisas antes, inclusive definindo uma variável chamada `list` em algum lugar, sobrescrevendo a estrutura `list` padrão do Python, causando o erro.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss resolvi o problema fazendo um restart no kernel do jupyter notebook

Comment: @RafaelSilva aproveite e crie uma resposta com a sua solução para que, quando alguém tiver o mesmo problema, saiba como arrumar também.

Comment: No meu caso eu estava utilizando o jupyter notebook e apenas fazendo o restart do kernel e tudo passou a funcionar.

Comment: @fernandosavio a resposta foi criada.

Comment: Muito bom. Teria como adicionar o comando usado pra fazer isso? Eu faria isso, mas como não trabalho muito com Jupyter não sei como faz.

Comment: E pode marcar sua resposta como a correta.

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

@fernandosavio é só apertar o botão marcado em vermelho no painel do jupyter.